# eclipse and opengl-es-2.0, info.reqGlEsVersion is zero

Tags: android, eclipse, opengl-es-2.0

when i try to run a program in eclipse with adt and od a check for

```
if(info.reqGlEsVersion <  0x20000)
```

it always fails.
I set a breakpoint and looked at the `info` object and the `reqGlEsVersion` is `0`

i tested this with multiple virtual devices and api's, one having version 2.3.3 another with 3.0. as far as i gould figure out the minimum requirement for gl es 2.0 is android 2.2 so it should run fine. other than chaning the api i used the device snapshot option and standard configuration

did i miss some configuration step or something?

btw the eclipse version is 2.5.1

Answer (score 5, accepted):

I followed advice from this link
http://www.learnopengles.com/android-emulator-now-supports-native-opengl-es2-0/

Comment from link is:

> Two notes about the GPU emulation
>
> First, you need to edit your emulator image, go down to the hardware section, and add “GPU Emulation” and set it to true.
>
> Second, there’s a bug with the emulator such that this line: “final boolean supportsEs2 = configurationInfo.reqGlEsVersion >=
> 0×20000;” does not work. It will always return false. You can add “||
> Build.FINGERPRINT.startsWith(“generic”)” or simply comment out these
> checks and assume that OpenGL ES 2 is supported, when running on the
> emulator.

Comment: You saved me with the “|| Build.FINGERPRINT.startsWith(“generic”)” workaround, thankyou.

Answer (score 0):

I was testing OpenGLES 2.0 on emulator with ARM cpu and API level 17 and it did not work. Some other posts say that it works with Intel Atom CPU type emulator. I tried it with new emulator and the same code [including the part when I added Build.FINGERPRINT.startsWith(“generic”)] works. Not sure about the exact reason, but can live it as long as testing OpenGL code is possible.